# Prove that the sum of harmonic series 1..n can be expressed as (n+1)H_n -n

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, harmonic-numbers

Prove by induction that the sum of harmonic series Hn from 1 to n where n is a natural number is as follows.
$$
H_n = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n 1/i 
$$
Prove:
$$
 \sum\limits_{i=1}^nH_i = (n+1)H_n -n 
$$
n=1
$$
H_1 = 1 = (1+1)(H_1) -1 = 2(1)-1 =1
$$
n=k+1
$$
H_{n+1} = H_n +1/(n+1)
$$
$$
H_1 +H_2 +... +H_{n+1} = (n+1 +1 )H_{n+1} -(n+1)
$$
$$
H_1 +H_2 +... +H_{n+1} = (n+2)H_{n+1} -n -1
$$
$$
H_1 +H_2 +... +H_{n+1} = (n+2)H_{n+1} -n -1
$$
$$
H_1 +H_2 +... +H_{n+1} = nH_{n+1} +2H_{n+1} -n -1
$$
$$
H_1 +H_2 +... +H_{n} = nH_{n+1} +2H_{n+1} -n -1 = (n+2)(H_{n+1}) -n -1
$$
$$
H_1 +H_2 +... +H_{n} =(n+2)(H_n +1)/(n+1) -n -1
$$
At this point I get lost.  I've been at this for a while and I don't know if I'm even on the right track, does anyone have a solution.  Did I go wrong anywhere?

Comment: You only need to write, since $H_1=1$, that $H_1 = 2 H_1-1$, but you really need to include $2H_1-1$ for clarity.

Comment: Induction is a good strategy. But don't assume the thing you're trying to prove ... you do that in the second line of your seven-equation group. Instead, start from $H_{n+1} = H_n + \frac1{n+1}$ and plug in the induction hypothesis for $H_n$; see if you can rewrite the resulting expression to deduce that second line (rather than assuming it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{n}H_{i} = \pars{n + 1}H_{n} - n:\ {\large ?}.\quad
     n\ \geq\ 1}$.

## By Induction:

It's obviously true for $\ds{n = 1}$. Lets assume that it's true for a given $\ds{n\ >\ 1}$. Then,
\begin{align}
&\color{#c00000}{\sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{n + 1}H_{i}}
=\sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{n}H_{i} + H_{n + 1}
=\pars{n + 1}H_{n} - n + H_{n + 1}
\\[5mm]&=\pars{n + 1}\pars{H_{n + 1} - {1 \over n + 1}} - n + H_{n + 1}
=\pars{n + 1}H_{n + 1} - 1 - n + H_{n + 1}
\\[5mm]&=\color{#c00000}{\bracks{\pars{n + 1} + 1}H_{n + 1} - \pars{n + 1}}
\end{align}

## In addittion:

> The direct proof becomes:
>   \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{n}H_{i}}
> =\sum_{i\ =\ 1}^{n}\sum_{k\ =\ 1}^{i}{1 \over k}
> =\sum_{k\ =\ 1}^{n}{1 \over k}\sum_{i\ =\ k}^{n}1
> =\sum_{k\ =\ 1}^{n}{1 \over k}\pars{n - k + 1}
> =\pars{n + 1}\sum_{k\ =\ 1}^{n}{1 \over k} - \sum_{k\ =\ 1}^{n}1
> \\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large\pars{n + 1}H_{n} - n}
> \end{align}